# Selenium get String value from Div OnClick element

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium

Im trying to get the email address from the following code but im not sure how to do it. Any help would be appreciated

```
<div class="taLnk hvrIE6 fl" onclick="ta.trackEventOnPage('Listing', 'Email', 7741695, 1); return ta.call('ta.locationDetail.checkEmailAction',event,this,'info@email.com', 7741695, '\x41\x6e\x20\x69\x6e\x71\x75\x69\x72\x79\x20\x66\x72\x6f\x6d\x20\x61\x20\x54\x72\x69\x70\x41\x64\x76\x69\x73\x6f\x72\x20\x75\x73\x65\x72\x20\x66\x6f\x72\x20\x41\x6e\x6e\x61\x4c\x65\x6e\x61', 'Restaurant_Url_Restaurant_Review');">
```

Comment: What you have tried? please share that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use Selenium to get the value of the onclick attribute and then use JAVA Strings to seperate out the required email.

```
// find the element and get the attribute value of onclick
String onClickValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class= 'taLnk hvrIE6 fl']")).getAttribute("onclick");

// split the onclick value on ','
String[] allTextArray = onClickValue.split(",");

// iterate through the array and is @ is contained with the text, print text
for (String text : allTextArray) {
    if (text.contains("@")) {
        System.out.println(text);
        return;
    }
}
```

Note: The XPath of the div might be different. I have written it based on what little HTML you posted.