# Trying to find a id in elements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I need help,

I'm trying to print the link from a website,
Here is how the code looks like:

```
<div class="tabla_szoveg">
            <div style="cursor:pointer" onclick="konyvjelzo('1523442');" class="torrent_konyvjelzo2"></div>
```

I'm trying to print the number inside "konyvjelzo('1523442');"

Using selenium

Also tried:

```
linkgettr= driver.find_element_by_class("box_torrent_all")
```

but getting NONE
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608225/selenium-get-string-value-from-div-onclick-element (be nice and don't hack ncore)

Comment: trying to make automate bot :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the partial *value* of *onclick* event i.e. **1523442** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following solution:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.tabla_szoveg>div.torrent_konyvjelzo2"))).get_attribute("onclick").split("'")[1])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[class='tabla_szoveg']/div[@class='torrent_konyvjelzo2']"))).get_attribute("onclick").split("'")[1])
  ```

Comment: Worked, Thank you so much

Comment: sorry,one more question
what if i want to add the number in this format:
example:
"google.com/"+number+"/download"

Comment: sorry,one more question
what if i want to add the number in this format:
example:
"google.com/"+number+"/download"

Comment: @perzsa Of coarse that should work too. In that case, don't print the number but store it as a variable.

Comment: Thank you so much again 
Helped me so much

Answer (score 1):

Please check if `torrent_konyvjelzo2` is dynamic ,if not then you can also replace below `torrent` text with it otherwise you can use below code as it is.

split("'")[1] is used to split your `konyvjelzo('1523442');` text

```
konyvjelzo( --> item 0
1523442     --> item 1
);          --> item 2
```

the first item index starts from 0. so we can return 1 item.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'torrent')]")))
attribute=element.get_attribute("onclick")
print attribute.split("'")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you could just use simple regex to find this easily

```
ids = re.findall("onclick=\"konyvjelzo\('(.*?)'\);",page_text)
```

Comment: getting error: TypeError: findall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'