# How to get onclick function from an element in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I have the following element:

```
<td id="content_gvNewLeads_tccell25_5" class="dxgv dx-ellipsis" align="left" style="border-bottom-width:0px;">
  <a onclick="return ShowCallDialog(493325, 7);">9 Via Cancion </a>
</td>
```

I need to get the value in "onclick" in this case `return ShowCallDialog(493325, 7)`

[Following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608225/selenium-get-string-value-from-div-onclick-element)
I attempted to do it like this:

```
allElements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@id,'content_gvNewLeads_tccel')]/a").getAttribute("onclick")
```

I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getAttribute'
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract them with a loop.

Use `.get_attribute("onclick")` not `.getAttribute("onclick")`:

```
allElements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@id,'content_gvNewLeads_tccel')]/a")

for element in allElements:
    print(element.get_attribute("onclick"))
```